# Is it possible to plant trees in minecraft earth?

Tags: minecraft-earth

I've just started playing Minecraft Earth and have been experimenting with the first 8x8 tile that you get.

I cut down the tree and the leaves, but didn't get an saplings.

My question is - *do you plant trees in the normal way like in standard Minecraft, or do you have to construct them entirely from blocks in your inventory?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now get [saplings](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft_Earth/comments/edte3j/sapling_can_be_obtained_in_game/) in [tree tappables](https://minecraft-earth.fandom.com/wiki/Tappable) or in adventure mode when you break leaves. You can plant the saplings in the ground and wait a bit to make them grow !

Thanks PausePause for the heads up

Comment: No longer true. Tree tappablesnow may drop sapplings as an "uncommon" or "epic" spawn dependent on tree species

Answer (score 1):

You have to place down the leaves and break them with a tool (pickaxe, axe, etc.) to have a chance of getting a sapling. You don’t get something every time but you can get them that way.

Comment: So you can grow trees in MC Earth now?